# Plots to illustrate results of linear mixed effect model

Tags: r, data-visualization, mixed-model

I've been analysing some data using linear mixed effect modelling in R. I'm planning to make a poster with the results and I was just wondering if anyone experienced with mixed effect models could suggest which plots to use in illustrating the results of the model.
I was thinking about residual plots, plot of fitted values vs original values, etc.

I know this will very much depend on my data but I was just trying to get a feel for the best way to illustrate results of linear mixed effect models. I'm using the nlme package in R.

Thanks

Comment: The book by [Pinheiro and Bates](http://www.amazon.com/Mixed-Effects-Models-S-PLUS-Statistics-Computing/dp/1441903178/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1400315348&sr=1-1) contains several examples. You could look at §4.3, "Examining a Fitted Model".

Comment: This thread can probably be helpful also: [What would be an illustrative picture for linear mixed models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/51186/what-would-be-an-illustrative-picture-for-linear-mixed-models/51187#51187)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends on your model, but, in my experience, even colleagues, who don't have a good understanding of mixed effects models, really like if you plot the predictions with different grouping levels:

```
library(nlme)
fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject)

newdat <- expand.grid(Sex=unique(Orthodont$Sex),
                  age=c(min(Orthodont$age),
                            max(Orthodont$age)))

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Orthodont, aes(x=age, y=distance, colour=Sex)) +
  geom_point(size=3) +
  geom_line(aes(y=predict(fm2), group=Subject, size="Subjects")) +
  geom_line(data=newdat, aes(y=predict(fm2, level=0, newdata=newdat), size="Population")) +
  scale_size_manual(name="Predictions", values=c("Subjects"=0.5, "Population"=3)) +
  theme_bw(base_size=22) 
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: @ Roland, thanks for your answer. My model is a linear mixed effect model containing independent and dependent variables with some covariates.

Comment: @ Roland, can I just ask if `fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age + Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject)` is the same as `fm3 <- lme(distance ~ age*Sex, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject) `. I'm trying to use Sex as a covariate for the model.

Comment: No. `age * Sex` is the same as `age + Sex + age:Sex`, i.e., it includes the interaction.

Comment: @ Roland, thanks for your answer. In that case could you kindly explain what `distance ~ age + Sex` means as opposed to `distance ~ age*Sex`.

Comment: As I told you, the latter includes the interaction between the variables, the former doesn't. Study `help("formula")`.

Comment: one last question-sry to trouble you. If I had a model that looks like fm2 <- lme(distance ~ age, data = Orthodont, random = ~ 1|Subject) (i.e. Sex has been removed from the formula), would that change anything in the code for the ggplot?

Comment: Yes, of course. You'd need to remove `colour=Sex`.

Comment: any ideas how I can change the colours of the two groups?

Comment: Yes, but that's basic ggplot2 functionalty. Study the documentation and tutorials. You might want to use `scale_colour_manual`.

Comment: @Roland, How could I include the confidence interval in this case? I created [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54239807/how-do-i-plot-a-single-numerical-covariate-using-emmeans-or-other-package-from) Could you have a look? Tks in advance!!

Comment: doing that provides me with broken lines instead of typical straight lines across the observations.

Comment: @AgusCamacho I just ran the code from this answer in an R session to check if something has changed since it was written. I still get the output shown here.